# Should I find the angle between a normal vector and a line to find the angle between the line and a plane?

Tags: solution-verification, vectors

I'm asked to find the angle between a line and a plane. I've calculated the normal vector of the plane to be $[7,4,-5]$ and the direction vector of the line to be $[3,-2,4]$. Is it right to find the angle between those two to figure out the angle between the line and the plane? I know that the normal vector and the plane meet at a 90-degree angle, so when I found that the lines direction vector and the planes normal vector have $\approx97.88°$ between them, is it right to assume that the angle between the line and the plane is $7.88°$?

Comment: Yep, looks good to me!